# How to get the top line of a text according to the text size set?

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint, textview

I am developing an app for writing text inside 3 lines.I was able to get the baseline of the text with the help of this code.

```
        mRect r = new Rect();
          for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {

        int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);

        Log.e("baseline","baseline:"+baseline);
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline, r.right, baseline, paint);
      }
```

now I was able to draw 3 lines and write the text aligned with this lines using this code

```
     for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {

        int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);

        Log.e("baseline","baseline:"+baseline);
        canvas.drawLine(r.left, baseline, r.right, baseline, paint);

        canvas.drawLine(r.left, r.top+10, r.right, r.top+10, paint);

        canvas.drawLine(r.left, (baseline+r.top+10)/2, r.right, (baseline+r.top+10)/2, paint1);

    }
```

The problem is when I tried the same thing on a different phone with different resolution everything was out of alignment,however the baseline was still perfectly aligned so i want to know is there another way to align the topline of the text.My textsize is 35 sp

Any help is really appreciated

Regards,

Comment: use StaticLayout class

Comment: I am not familiar with that class can u explain a little bit.Thanks for the reply

Comment: just read its documentation